# Real life Java Swing Project

Tags: java, swing, architecture

I've been working with swing for the last 2 years, but i'm still not satisfy with my own work.
The apps are "fast" enough, but the development isn't enough "clean".

Can you recommend me any real world project, book, or something similar that shows me how a real world swing app work. May be a framework, something structured, etc.

For example, i'm thinking i may code a "window manager" that has all the window of the app in an unified resource, may be cached, etc. I think all those good ideas must be implemented already.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you to have a look at the [NetBeans Rich client platform](http://platform.netbeans.org/) or the [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=983225) source code - those are two of the most prominent open source Swing applications in existence.

Comment: Thanks brother, i've heard about it. I think it's a good idea. I'll give it a try.
Another question: Is there anything standarized for the "updates"? I mean. I'm trying to implement it, and is giving a real hard time.

Comment: If you want to see a real world example, see the "Elster-programme" (it is in german). It is a Desktop programme and afaik written in Java and Swing: https://www.elster.de/elfo_down.php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source of the [swing application framework](https://appframework.dev.java.net/).

Comment: The link does not exist. Here is the "Better SAF": https://kenai.com/projects/bsaf/pages/Home

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [GUTS-GUI](http://kenai.com/projects/guts/pages/Home), a Swing Application Framework, based on [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) Dependency Injection library.

Its concepts are mostly the same as the "[Swing Application Framework](https://appframework.dev.java.net/)" (also known as JSR-296), but its design is much cleaner (and more easily extensible) and better adapted to dependency injection (which is extremely hard to achieve with SAF).

GUTS-GUI comes with a simple example application (not a real-life one yet, sorry).

GUTS-GUI also includes an "Event Bus" which is generally considered a good way to communicate (in a decoupled manner for easier maintainability) between components of a GUI application.

Please note that GUTS-GUI is still in development stage current stage, but well advanced already in terms of Swing design, best practices for GUI development...